# How can i save relation in django rest by posting complete object in PrimarykeyRelated Field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Suppose i have this model

```
class Track(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Now in my class TrackSerializer if i use this

```
user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(required=False)
```

then i can post the `track = {user: 1}` and it correctly saves it

Now my problem is in my json i always have complete object like complete user object like

`track = {user: {id: 1, name: 'test'}}`

then i get error that `expect pk and got dict`

Is there any way that i can post complete object and system automatically takes pk from it.

The problem is i don't want to declare complete serializers separately for all models  . eg

`update_by` is usually `User` object and Django rest automatically takes it as primary key related field.  There if want to use complete `User` object then i have decalre it explicitly as `UserSerializer`

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into [nested](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-nested-objects) [serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization).

Comment: The problem with nested sserializer is that it always try to add that as new entry in database . I mean it don't add only relation. it either adds object or not. i don't add relation if object already exists

Comment: Take a look at [this thread](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/2304) between me and the creator of DRF.  I'm not happy with nested serializer behavior myself...  I think it needs to be reworked.